# Microsoft Access 2007 Database on Django?

Tags: sql-server, django, ms-access, odbc, crm

I have a Microsoft Access 2007 database (.accdb) used in a CRM, and I'd very much like to create an unmanaged model in django to access the data (read-only) for a quick and dirty web application.

What are my options here? I looked at django-pyodbc, but they unfortunately only support ms sql connections at this time. That made me wonder, perhaps there is a way to mirror a Microsoft Access database to a MS SQL server through ODBC, and then connect to that through the django-mssql or django-pyodbc application?

Another option is to convert the access database to some intermediary database file which could then be accessed through django. The downfall to this approach is that I'd need to ensure that I regularly syncronize this intermediary database with the access database, so the intermediary db is up to date.

**Does anyone have any ideas on how I can connect to my Access 2007 CRM data through django?**

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the problem, but you can use a linked server to Access/Jet/ACE so that a SQL Server can be used to get to the data.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Your idea intrigues me, but I'm not quite sure how to approach it (I'm more of a LAMP guy, so I'm less familiar with the windows stack). Would you mind posting some more details in the form of an answer below? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server person, but I know that SQL Server allows you to create what are called "linked servers". They are kind of like Access linked tables, in that the data in the non-SQL Server data source is available to you within SQL Server. Surely there's plenty of documentation on that.

Answer (score 1):

Access files really don't like more than one person touching them. You've outgrown them. Get a proper multi-user networked database and migrate to that. Microsoft will sell you SQL Server for the price of a small yacht or give you SQL Express for free in the hope that soon you'll need to upgrade.

Or use PostgreSQL via ODBC for free for ever. But don't try and use a file as a database without going through a server first.

Comment: The access database is part of the CRM that we use (http://www.pcesoft.com). I'd be willing to explore alternatives to it if you have any to suggest. In the mean time, I was hoping to whip up a quick and dirty read-only frontend to access certain data within the database.

Comment: odbc will do it. plenty of resources around for that. Try not to corrupt or lock your database :)

Comment: I will probably end up hacking something together using pyodbc, it's just a shame that I can't get it up and running on django.

Comment: -1 for the COMPLETELY FALSE first sentence. Please stop spreading misiniformation about applications you don't understand and have obviously not really used.

Comment: Wrong, MS Access can handle multiple users, since at least Office 2003. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167840(v=office.11).aspx